# How to edit these parts of the code without data tags and how to edit the methods relevant to them?

Tags: reactjs

There is a code of my main application file - App.js. I'll write it at the bottom of the question.

And my code reviewer told me that in it I need to change these two parts in the file App.js:

First part:

```
{daysArray.map((day, i) => (
  <button key={day} onClick={() => this.changeDay(i)} className={i === this.state.day ? "active" : ""}>{day}
</button>
  ))}
```

Second part:

```
{Object.keys(startDataArray).map(item => (
          <button data-category={item} onClick={this.changeCategory} className={item === category ? "active" : ""}>{item} category</button>
 ))}
```

method to the first part:

```
changeDay = (argDay) => {
    this.setState({
        day: argDay
      },this.fetchData);
  };
```

method to the second part:

```
changeCategory = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
        category: event.target.dataset.category 
    },this.filter);
  };
```

He said that it was not need to use any `data tags` (that is, not to use `key` and `data-category`, and demonstrated an example on another code (Redux + React) as needed to be edit.
Here is an example:
from this code:

```
{data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
 <button data-shift={n} onClick={e => onFilter({ shift: e.target.dataset.shift })} className={n === shift ? "active" : "noActive"}>
       {n}
  </button>
  ))}
```

edit to this:

```
{data && Object.keys(data).map(n => (
  <button onClick={()=> onFilter({ shift: n })} className={n === shift ? "active" : "noActive"}>
       {n}
  </button>
  ))}
```

I tried, by analogy with the example of the person who checked (Redux-React), to edit my code without data tags and removed the `dataset` and other unnecessary ones in the methods themselves. But unfortunately nothing works. How to edit these parts of the code without data tags and the relevant methods to make it work?

and the App.js file code itself:

```
const daysArray = ["yesterday", "today", "tomorrow"];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    day: 1,
    startDataArray: [],
    filteredDataArray: [],
    searchInput: "",
    category: "first"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`/data/${daysArray[this.state.day]}.json`);
    const data = (await response.json()).group;
    this.setState({
        startDataArray: data,
        category: Object.keys(data)[0] 
      },this.filter);
  };

  changeDay = (argDay) => {
    this.setState({
        day: argDay
      },this.fetchData);
  };

  updateSearchInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: e.target.value
    });
  };

  filter = () => {
    this.setState(
      ({ searchInput, startDataArray, category}) => {
        return {
          filteredDataArray: startDataArray[category].filter(item =>
            item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
          )
        };
      }
    );
  };

  changeCategory = (event) => {
    this.setState({ 
        category: event.target.dataset.category 
    },this.filter);
  };

  render() {
    const {searchInput, category, startDataArray, filteredDataArray} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <TableSearch value={searchInput} onChange={this.updateSearchInput} onSearch={this.filter}/>

        {daysArray.map((day, i) => (
          <button key={day} onClick={() => this.changeDay(i)} className={i === this.state.day ? "active" : ""}>{day}</button>
        ))}

        <br />

        {Object.keys(startDataArray).map(item => (
          <button data-category={item} onClick={this.changeCategory} className={item === category ? "active" : ""}>{item} category</button>
        ))}

        <TableData dataAttribute={filteredDataArray} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tag `<button>` has attribute `value`. You can pass the item (I hope item is id) to value. And get value from event.currentTarget.value on listener `changeCategory`