# What I did not correctly redone in mapStateToProps and in the render method that I got errors? And what to fix?

Tags: reactjs, redux

There is a code for one Redux-React application that can help me write my new own project, but I met such an entry there:

`const mapStateToProps = state => state;`

I hadn’t written this way before, besides one person said to change and make something like this (example from another code):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    onLike: state.propReducer.like
});
```

And I change mapStateToProps and what in my opinion needed to be redone in the `render` method (I'm new to Redux), but I got errors and the application stopped working:

```
./src/containers/app.js
Line 47:29: 'stateToPropsSearchInput' is not defined no-undef
Line 52:12: 'stateToPropsStartDataArray' is not defined no-undef
Line 52:54: 'stateToPropsStartDataArray' is not defined no-undef
Line 53:169: 'stateToPropsCategory' is not defined no-undef
Line 65:95: 'stateToPropsDay' is not defined no-undef
Line 71:10: 'stateToPropsStartDataArray' is not defined no-undef
Line 71:66: 'stateToPropsFilteredDataArray' is not defined no-undef
```

All project in sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/white-wind-o1ogd

I will write a working version of the part of the App.js file before the changes and not working after the changes. Let the big code not scare you, I wrote more code to make it more understandable, because I only changed the body of the mapStateToProps method, and in the render method in all places I changed the names of the properties of the state (from the reducer) to the properties that I invented in the mapStateToProps method, that is stateToPropsSearchInput and so on.... Please help me fix mapStateToProps and tell me what to fix in the body of the render method.

A code variant that works well (before the changes):

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(daysArray[this.props.propsReducer.day]);
  }

  render() {
    const { onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;
    const { day, startDataArray, filteredDataArray, searchInput, category} = this.props.propsReducer;

    return (
      <div>

        <TableSearch value={searchInput} onChange={e => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
         onSearch={value => onFilter({ searchInput: value })}/>

          {startDataArray && Object.keys(startDataArray).map(element => (
            <button data-category={element} onClick={e => onFilter({ category: e.target.dataset.category })} className={element === category ? "active" : "noActive"}>
                {element}
            </button>
          ))}


          {daysArray && daysArray.map((element, index) => (
            <button key={element} onClick={() => onFetchData(element)} className={element === day ? "activeDay" : "noActiveDay"}>
                {element} 
            </button>
          ))}

        {startDataArray && <TableData dataAttribute={filteredDataArray} />}

          </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state;

const matchDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onFilter: args => dispatch(filter(args)),
    onSetSearch: search => dispatch(setSearch(search)),
    onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
});
```

Code version where the application does not work(after my changes):

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchData(daysArray[this.props.propsReducer.day]);
  }

  render() {
    const { onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData } = this.props;
    const {
      stateToPropsDay,
      stateToPropsStartDataArray,
      stateToPropsFilteredDataArray,
      stateToPropsSearchInput,
      stateToPropsCategory
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>


        <TableSearch value={stateToPropsSearchInput} onChange={e => onSetSearch(e.target.value)} 
         onSearch={value => onFilter({ stateToPropsSearchInput: value })}/>
          {stateToPropsStartDataArray && Object.keys(stateToPropsStartDataArray).map(element => (
            <button data-stateToPropsCategory={element} onClick={e => onFilter({ stateToPropsCategory: e.target.dataset.stateToPropsCategory })} className={element === stateToPropsCategory ? "active" : "noActive"}>
                {element}
            </button>
          ))}



          {daysArray && daysArray.map((element, index) => (
            <button key={element} onClick={() => onFetchData(element)} className={element === stateToPropsDay ? "activeDay" : "noActiveDay"}>
                {element} 
            </button>
          ))}

        {stateToPropsStartDataArray && <TableData dataAttribute={stateToPropsFilteredDataArray} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    stateToPropsDay: state.propReducer.day,
    stateToPropsStartDataArray: state.propReducer.startDataArray,
    stateToPropsFilteredDataArray: state.propReducer.filteredDataArray,
    stateToPropsSearchInput: state.propReducer.searchInput,
    stateToPropsCategory: state.propReducer.category
});


const matchDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onFilter: args => dispatch(filter(args)),
    onSetSearch: search => dispatch(setSearch(search)),
    onFetchData: day => dispatch(fetchData(day))
});

export const ConnectedRoot = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  matchDispatchToProps
)(Root);
```

in reducer, I passed a state like this:

```
state = {    
     day: 1,
      startDataArray: [],
      filteredDataArray: [],
      searchInput: "",
      category: "departure"
    }
```

and the combineReducers file looks like this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  propsReducer: reducer
});
```

Comment: Hi anton. I wonder if I could trouble you to explain [why this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889432/how-to-edit-these-parts-of-the-code-without-data-tags-and-how-to-edit-the-method) was deleted? It looked like it had a short (though rather brief) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to connect **Root** (you probably done this)

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Root)
```

see https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect

2. You access all those attributes as props in your component

```js
const { onFilter, onSetSearch, onFetchData, stateToPropsStartDataArray } = this.props;
```

All these you can access from **this.props**.something

[image]

Comment: I did not understand, can you fix the bugs in the sandbox? 
https://codesandbox.io/s/white-wind-o1ogd

Comment: @antongordon25 here is it fixed https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-galileo-7o6eb

Comment: @antongordon25
2 errors
1. in reducers/index there was typo with propsReducer and in your component you ask for propReducer
2. in App :
this.props.onFetchData(daysArray[this.props.stateToPropsDay]);  // Removed propsReducer.

Comment: thank you very much but my arrival and departure buttons stopped working, why?

Comment: @antongordon25 I think you should update your reducer to check stateToPropsCategory value

Comment: can you help me update reducer? I tried to do as you said in the reducer but all the data disappeared....